# Optimising a node.js falcor router between a traditional REST API data source and a Falcor client

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, falcor, falcor-router

I have a traditional REST API, that returns data like so:

#### User list - `GET /users.json`

```
users: [
    {id: 0, name: "John Smith"},
    ...
]
```

#### Users by Id - `GET /users/0.json`

```
user: {
    id: 0,
    name: "John Smith"
}
```

As you can see, if you first request the data from the list (`/users.json`), and then click on a user, even though the information was present in the first list, it is re-requested from the user by id request.

In Falcor, this would be solved by having a list of references in the first call.

My question is, if I am writing a Falcor router to act as a middleman, how do I optimise such a scenario? Currently, the router has to request the full user list, and then throw out the information and return a list of references based on the ids to the client. This still saves bandwidth on the client side but is suboptimal between the Falcor router and its datasource (REST API).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to workaround this situation, but first, I would like to explain why you are seeing this mismatch. It is because Falcor respect REST principles, but your API does not. REST states that data coming from the API should be cacheable. It cannot be cacheable if it resides in two places at once. For example, if I were to `PUT` or `PATCH` `/users/0.json`, how can the client know that this operation has an impact on `/users.json` (a different resource) and invalidate its cache? It cannot. In fully-compliant HTTP REST APIs and Falcor APIs alike, data resides in one place only, and then it can be linked to via refs. For HTTP, refs are URLs, and so a `GET` call to `/users.json` should respond with a list of URLs like `["/users/0.json", "/users/1.json"]`.

That said, it does not mean you are out of luck.

What you probably want on the Falcor side is to have a route like this: `users[{integers:indices}][{keys:props}]`. In the handler for this route, you can query `pathSet.indices` and see how much indices were actually requested. If there is only one (or few), forward the request to `/users/${indices[i]}.json`, otherwise forward it to `/users.json`.

Comment: Yes indeed, and unfortunately I'm not responsible for the origin API so my question was about how to deal with a bad situation!

Comment: But that leaves me with more questions - I do know that ideally `/users/` or `/users.json` should respond with a list of references. But on the other hand, if you're using it to populate a list of users, isn't it more efficient to actually provide much of the data in the list? (Considering the table of users displayed has ~10 columns). If you would return simply a reference, the browser (or the Falcor middleman, but its less of a problem here) would have to make 1 request per page + 1 request per user, easily hitting 100s or 1000s of calls just to populate a table.

Comment: Yes, that's how it is supposed to work. REST implies a lot of requests, but caching compensates. I'm not implying REST is better in any way, I was simply trying to explain the mismatch between Falcor and your API. You can watch one of the Falcor talks by Jafar Hussain from Netflix, it contains a good overlook of REST-vs-RPC-style HTTP APIs. It's a trade-off.

Comment: I looked at it and decided to add a second API version to serve Falcor. It just isn't worth the trouble working around the original API. With the jsonapi spec the sparse fieldsets provide exactly what Falcor needs (`GET /users/?fields[users]=id` returns only the `id` attribute and nothing else)